# ¿Cómo se legalizan los superlativos irregulares?

Tags: rae, formas-irregulares, superlativos

Por ejemplo hoy estaba buscando [buenísimo](http://dle.rae.es/buen%C3%ADsimo) en el [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) y veo que la palabra no se encuentra, en su lugar veo [bonísimo, ma](http://dle.rae.es/bon%C3%ADsimo).

Entonces me dirijo al [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=buenisimo) y me encuentro que me redirige a la palabra bueno.

> a) buenísimo. Superlativo regular, formado sobre el adjetivo español bueno + el sufijo superlativo -ísimo (→ -ísimo): «Conmigo siempre ha sido buenísimo» (Benedetti Primavera [Ur. 1982]); «Es una idea buenísima y original» (AMillán Guardapolvo [Esp. 1990]). Es hoy forma mucho más usada que bonísimo (→ b).

y

> b) bonísimo. Superlativo irregular, formado con la raíz del adjetivo latino bonus + el sufijo superlativo -ísimo: «A esta Basi la temo, es bonísima, pero se enrolla como una persiana» (MtnGaite Fragmentos [Esp. 1976]); «Ella me enseñó a hacer el cordero con patatas al horno, que es bonísimo» (Castro/Alcántara/Colón Cocina [R. Dom. 1996]). Esta forma está cayendo en desuso y hoy se prefiere buenísimo (→ a).

Por lo menos yo nunca había escuchado `bonísimo`, aunque ahi mismo aclaran que ya está en desuso.

**¿Cómo es que se adopta en la Real Academia de la Lengua Española estos superlativos/verbos/adjetivos cualquier cosa que sea irregular?**

Comment: Es normal que no encuentres `buenísimo`; los superlativos regulares no aparecen en el diccionario, igual que no aparece ninguna palabra derivada de forma normal, a menos que tenga un significado especial.

Comment: Técnicamente, *bonísimo* no es irregular *per se* — la palabra *bueno* presenta una alternancia vocálica (una característica mejor vista en los verbos como *acostar*).  Cuando se acentúa la sílaba alternante, sale *ue*, pero cuando carece de acentuación, sale *o*.  Por eso, tenemos bueno, bondad, bonísimo, bondadoso, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí está descrito el proceso → http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/como-se-hace-el-diccionario

Nota relacionada: http://www.20minutos.es/noticia/2043343/0/nuevo/diccionario/rae/

Básicamente, tienen comisiones que proponen agregados, enmiendas o supresiones, y las academias americanas también proponen. Finalmente, deciden los “académicos de número” ([este grupo](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/los-academicos/academicos-de-numero/relacion-actual) de españoles).

Comment: No todos son españoles. Mario Vargas Llosa es peruano, por ejemplo. Pero sí que es cierto que Mario Vargas Llosa es muy conocido en España.

Comment: :( Wikipedia dice que Mario Vargas Llosa también tiene la nacionalidad española. La verdad que sería interesante saber si la nacionalidad española es condición necesaria para ser miembro.

Comment: que son las letras que aparecen al lado del nombre, en este [link](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/los-academicos/academicos-de-numero/relacion-actual)

Comment: A cada miembro le asignan una letra, mayúscula o minúscula.

Comment: ¡Qué curioso! Siendo "Académicos de número", les asignan una letra ... :)

Comment: @Nico según los [Statutos](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Estatutos_1993.pdf) artículo 8, inciso c `De Académicos Correspondientes extranjeros. Serán igualmente Académicos Correspondientes los miembros de número de las Academias Correspondientes` un poco de travalengua, pero parece que sí pueden ser extranjeros

Comment: @EmilioGort Los que importan son los del inciso **a**, los "de número". Y estos tienen que, por lo menos, residir en España, para poder participar de las sesiones. En el estatuto no dice nada sobre ciudadanía, aunque al ser un organismo del Estado español tal vez haya restricciones generales que correspondan (lo dudo).

Comment: @angus leyendo el artículo 3, entiendo que los diccionarios tienen personal y órganos de gobierno propio. Mi interpretación, entonces, es que los académicos de número no son los responsables actualizar el diccionario.

Comment: Siempre los textos legales me han dado un poco de trabajo, entiendo cosas más abstractas, pero leer statutos siempre me ha dado dolor de cabeza :)

Answer (score 3):

'Bonísimo' es la forma tradicional, 'buenísimo' es un neologismo del siglo dieciocho que solo la sobrepaso a partir de los años sesenta: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bon%C3%ADsimo,buen%C3%ADsimo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,bon%C3%ADsimo;,c0;,s0;;bon%C3%ADsimo;,c0;;Bon%C3%ADsimo;,c0;.t4;,buen%C3%ADsimo;,c0;,s0;;buen%C3%ADsimo;,c0;;Buen%C3%ADsimo;,c0)