# ¿Cuál es el superlativo de "grande"? ¿Es "grandérrimo" correcto?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, sufijos, superlativos

En [¿Cómo se legalizan los superlativos irregulares?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5220/1674) se abrió el interesante debate sobre cómo se *normalizan* (*legalizan*) los superlativos que se salen de lo normal.

Refloto este debate al hilo de lo que leía ahora:

> Que Arnaldo Otegi esté escocido con el nombramiento de Grande Marlaska en Interior es una **buena noticia** para Sánchez. Que Quim Torra tenga los pelos de punta con Borrell en Exteriores es una **grandísima noticia** para Pedro Sánchez. Que Ana Patricia Botín haya saludado con entusiasmo a Nadia Calviño en Economía es una **grandérrima noticia** para Sánchez.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [No es un gobierno de izquierdas, por eso es inteligente](https://www.lamarea.com/2018/06/07/no-es-un-gobierno-de-izquierdas-por-eso-es-inteligente/)</sub>

Como veis, el autor va haciendo una gradación *bueno → grande → grandérrimo* utilizando el sufijo *-érrimo*.

En efecto, se está construyendo un superlativo que "encaja" en lo habitual para crear [superlativos de adjetivos](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Grado_superlativo):

> El grado superlativo del adjetivo se puede expresar de varias formas:
>
> - Añadiendo delante del adjetivo el adverbio de cantidad *muy*.
> - Mediante derivación, añadiendo los sufijos *-ísima*, *-ísimo*, *-érrima*, *-érrimo*.
> - En el habla popular, a menudo se utiliza también la prefijación. Algunos de los prefijos utilizados son: *requete-*, *sobre-*, *super-* o *extra-*.
> - Mediante otros recursos formales. Por ejemplo, añadiendo algún adverbio (superlativo perifrástico):
> - También con expresiones y frases hechas con *más que*.

Sin embargo, *grandérrimo* en concreto nunca lo había oído. ¿Qué tan común es? ¿Qué otro superlativo puede tener *grande*?

Comment: Sé que no viene a cuento, pero tengo que decirlo: menos mal que se me ha ocurrido mirar el artículo original. Ese párrafo fuera de contexto, y con ese título, engaña, y mucho.

Comment: @FGSUZ pues no sé, y seguramente sería algo para tratar en [politics.se], pero no me parece que vaya demasiado desencaminado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En latín, el sufijo superlativo natural de los adjetivos sustantivados era -*issimus* (de donde viene *-ísimo*), pero cuando una palabra tuviera un raíz en *-ro-*, la forma sería [*-errimus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-issimus#Usage_notes), de donde viene *-érrimo*<sup>1</sup>. Tales palabras son muy poco comunes:

- *acérrimo, aspérrimo, celebérrimo, integérrimo, libérrimo, misérrimo, nigérrimo, paupérrimo, pulquérrimo, salubérrimo, ubérrimo*

Y por eso, *-érrimo* no es tan productivo como *-ísimo*. De hecho, esta lista de palabras es muy culta, hasta el punto que las formas:

- *agrísimo, asperísimo, negrísimo, pobrísimo, pulcrísimo*

también existen y son ["igualmente válidos y aceptados en la norma culta"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=-%C3%A9rrimo) (DPD, *érrimo*).

Etimologicamente, *grandérrimo* no es 'correcto', puesto que la forma en latín era [*grandissimus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grandissimus) (> *grandísimo*). 
 Sin embargo en el castellano actual, podemos utilizar y mezclar cada manera de sufijos superlativo y diminutivo por razones de estilo. Por ejemplo, en tu cita, el autor ya ha usado la palabra *grandísima*, y emplea *-érrimo* para significar algo más fuerte que *-íssimo*, análogo a como podemos usar *-ín* etc para contrastar algo más diminuto que *-ito* (aunque en aislamiento significan más o menos lo mismo).

---

<sup>1. Cuando un adjetivo tenía un raíz en *-lo-*, el sufijo superlativo sería *-illimus*, pero no conozco ningún ejemplo español que termina en **-ílimo*.</sup>